# Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock

Tags: apt, lock

when I try to apt-get update I'm getting the below error,

```
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
```

Answer (score 73):

This just means that there is an application using apt.

First try to find out which application it is by using this command in the terminal

```
ps aux | grep '[a]pt'
```

If there is a process running using apt (like apt-get or aptitude), the best thing to do is just to let it finish what its doing. Otherwise you can kill it using

```
kill <PID of the process (2nd column in output of ps aux)>
```

After making sure there is no process or killing it, you can just remove the lock using

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/lock
```

Comment: drop the second pipe by adding some square brackets `ps aux | grep [a]pt`

Comment: The trick by @shtuff.it requires quotes for me `ps aux |grep "[t]mux"` .  It works by changing the `ps` `COMMAND` listing for `grep` into `grep [t]mux`, which does not match the regex `[t]mux` .  Clever.

Answer (score 3):

You can find out which process is using the file with `fuser` and optionally kill it:

```
sudo fuser -vik -TERM /var/lib/apt/lists/lock
```

Comment: This type of error : Unable to lock directory could occur when there is a software update happening in parallel. Not more than one sudo code can call the root directory at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

try this commad :
**sudo fuser -vik -TERM /var/lib/apt/lists/lock**

The fuser command is a Linux utility designed to find which process is using a given file, directory, or socket. It also provides information about the user owning running that process, and the type of access.