# How to edit the notification configuration?

Tags: gnome

The notification blip that usually comes on top-right and becomes slightly transparent on hover gets its colour from the background wallpaper, but can I edit it with more options? if yes, then how?

[image]

Comment: Do you want a specific option?

Comment: No, nothing specific. I would make my mind after seeing all options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for NotifyOSDConfiguration. Try

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install notifyosdconfig
```

then either search from the dash for "notify" or run in terminal

```
NotifyOSDConfiguration
```

Capitals matter.

Comment: Sorry, but that didn't work. Couldn't find the package.
http://i.imgur.com/yYM5VXB.jpg

Comment: Sorry, try the edit.

Comment: `root@AbhimanyuPC:~# sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8'.
Please check that the PPA name or format is correct.`

Comment: `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ca-certificates` then try again.

Comment: Did that work ?

Comment: It says resource temporarily unavailable and I can't run `sudo apt-get update`. `E: Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/`

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/335794/could-not-get-lock-var-lib-apt-lists-lock

Comment: Ah it worked, some other app was using it at that time. I retried and I can now open the app. Thanks a lot! :D