# Installing MATLAB in Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: 17.04, matlab

I was trying to install MATLAB in pc. I used the command,

```
sudo apt-get install matlab-gdf dynare-matlab libpdl-io-matlab-perl matlab-support matlab-support-dev matlab2tikz
```

, however I came across this error message.

```
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/t/texlive-base/texlive-pictures-doc_2016.20170123-5_all.deb  Connection failed [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8001::11 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

amd then I ran the command

```
sudo apt-get update
```

, still got the message:

```
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
```

could some one help me out with this? if I can still install it, please tell me what should I do?

if it's not installable, please tell me how to remove it completely and thoroughly from my PC.

Thanks a million! :)

Comment: The second error is because something is already using `apt`, see [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/335794/could-not-get-lock-var-lib-apt-lists-lock#335801). Have you tried rebooting the computer and then running `sudo apt-get update` first and then the install command? Maybe it was just a momentary network connection issue.

Comment: @oldmansaur: followed your suggestions, was be able to get the terminal install updates. Thank you very much for that! :) When I search for MATLAB, it didn't show up, does that mean it might have  not installed correctly ?

Comment: as far as I can see all the packages you installed are support packages for Matlab but not Matlab itself. I think you have to download an installer from Mathworks and follow their [instructions](https://de.mathworks.com/help/install/ug/install-mathworks-software.html).