# Upgrade to Ubuntu 17.10 asks for fglrx!

Tags: filesystem, fglrx

I have tried to upgrade from Ubuntu 16.04 to 17.10 but when I start the process by entering sudo apt update && sudo apt dist-upgrade in my terminal I get the message "The package fglrx needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it".  I'm confused.  I thought fglrx was obsolete.  Why is the new version of Ubuntu asking for it?  Any help gratefully received!

**Update** - I have tried to install amdgpu-pro as I believe fglrx is not used by Ubuntu 16.04.  But here too I get the same message.  Why does amdgpu-pro need fglrx?  I thought that it replaced it?

Perhaps I do have an issue with my software sources.  How might I solve this, please?

**Further update**.  Karel, thanks for this advice.  `sudo apt remove --purge fglrx fglrx-amdcccle* fglrx-dev* fglrx-updates*` returns:

```
Reading package lists... Done    
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done    
E: The package fglrx needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
```

Strange that the command to purge fglrx seems to want me to reinstall it!

/etc/apt/sources.list returns:

```
bash: /etc/apt/sources.list: Permission denied
```

If I in any case go ahead an copy the source file you suggested and run `apt-get update` I get:

```
Reading package lists... Done  
W: chmod 0700 of directory /var/lib/apt/lists/partial failed - SetupAPTPartialDirectory (1: Operation not permitted)  
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (13: Permission denied)  
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/  
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/pkgcache.bin - RemoveCaches (13: Permission denied)  
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/srcpkgcache.bin - RemoveCaches (13: Permission denied)
```

Any further help gratefully received!

**Third update**.  Karel, thanks for your help.  cat /etc/apt/sources.list returns something similar to the model.  I can't post the whole output as I get an error message that I can't post more than eight links unless I have reputation of 10 or more.  But the differences seem to be that (1) whereas the model refers to the US archive all references in mine are to the GB archive (which is what I should expect, (2) there are references at the beginning and end to Raring Ringtail, which puzzle me (are they significant?) and (3) the deb-src lines that are commented in the model are live in mine.  I post relevant extracts below and should be grateful for any further advice you can give.

# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 13.04 *Raring Ringtail* - Release amd64 (20130424)]/ raring main restricted

deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted
deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe
deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates multiverse
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu raring partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu raring partner

**Fourth update**.  I have tried to solve the problem by replacing my apt.sources.list file with the model file you pointed me to, replacing us.archive with gb.archive throughout.  But I don't think this has worked.  Sudo apt-update returns:

W: chmod 0700 of directory /var/lib/apt/lists/partial failed - SetupAPTPartialDirectory (1: Operation not permitted)
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/pkgcache.bin - RemoveCaches (13: Permission denied)
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/srcpkgcache.bin - RemoveCaches (13: Permission denied)
W: Target Packages (partner/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:49 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/xenial-partner.list:4
W: Target Packages (partner/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:49 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/xenial-partner.list:4
W: Target Packages (partner/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:49 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/xenial-partner.list:4
W: Target Translations (partner/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:49 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/xenial-partner.list:4
W: Target Translations (partner/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:49 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/xenial-partner.list:4
W: Target DEP-11 (partner/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:49 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/xenial-partner.list:4
W: Target DEP-11-icons (partner/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:49 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/xenial-partner.list:4

.... and `sudo apt-upgrade` returns the same with, at the end,

E: The package fglrx needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it

Does this new information help anybody to advise me on what to do next, please?

Comment: If it's asking then it was installed at same time before (and you didn't install updates for 16.04). And the commands you mention do NOT upgrade the release. You're still in 16.04 and you have issues with your software sources.

Comment: I didn't want you to copy or change anything in `/etc/apt/sources.list` only to read that file. The command to read it is `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock](https://askubuntu.com/questions/335794/could-not-get-lock-var-lib-apt-lists-lock)

Answer (score 1):

The fglrx package is not available in the default repositories of Ubuntu 16.04 and later, so get rid of the `The package fglrx needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it` error message by uninstalling all of the fglrx packages. Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get purge fglrx fglrx-amdcccle* fglrx-dev* fglrx-updates*
```

Then compare your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file with this [example Ubuntu 16.04 sources.list file](http://www.configserverfirewall.com/ubuntu-linux/etc-apt-sources-list-ubuntu-16-xenial/). Run the command `cat /etc/apt/sources.list` to read the sources.list file without changing it.

To fix the last errors follow the instructions in the answers to [How can I fix apt error "W: Target Packages … is configured multiple times"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760896/how-can-i-fix-apt-error-w-target-packages-is-configured-multiple-times).