# Getting error while installing node.js in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, apt, nodejs

I am getting this error when I run `curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | sudo bash -`
to install node.js

> - apt-get update
>     W: chmod 0700 of directory /var/lib/apt/lists/partial failed - SetupAPTPartialDirectory (1: Operation not permitted)
>     E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
>     E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
>     W: Problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/pkgcache.bin - RemoveCaches (13: Permission denied)
>     W: Problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/srcpkgcache.bin - RemoveCaches (13: Permission denied)
>     E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
>     E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
>     Error executing command, exiting

Comment: just remove it with type `sudo rm -f /var/lib/apt/lists/lock && sudo rm -f /var/lib/dpkg/lock` and update/upgrade and run your "sudo curl" sir

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock](https://askubuntu.com/questions/335794/could-not-get-lock-var-lib-apt-lists-lock)