# Unable to install and update many things on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: apt, permissions

I am unable to install and update many things on Ubuntu 18.04 because the terminal always shows:

```
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/pkgcache.bin - RemoveCaches (13: Permission denied)
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/srcpkgcache.bin - RemoveCaches (13: Permission denied)
```

Comment: Just to make sure. Are you using root ( sudo ) while running this commando?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock](https://askubuntu.com/questions/335794/could-not-get-lock-var-lib-apt-lists-lock)

Answer (score 0):

You need to run update commands `apt-get update` or `apt-get upgrade` with superuser a.k.a. root privileges, i.e.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: thanks so much ... but the command of denial just changed a little from "cant open/lock file or directory (/var/lib/LIST....), to.......E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?

Comment: Actually what happened some other software like software updater might be using `apt` or `dpkg` right now. You can remove explicitly lock using `rm -r /var/lib/dpkg/lock*` or wait for the process which is using that to exit.

Comment: now the other issue am having is how to install ubuntu mate because my software center refused to install it?

Comment: @LordLulent If you found the answer helpful, mark it as accepted by clicking on ✓. Also, it is highly recommended to have a question focused on a single issue. Please ask a new question for the same with more details. Thanks :-)