# accidentally deleted /var/lib/apt/

Tags: command-line, apt, files

I accidentally deleted content of /var/lib/apt with command below:

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/*
```

what should I do now? can I restore it? is it necessary?

Comment: the reason behind this accident is that I was trying to remove **/var/lib/apt/lists/*** because of its huge size to create empty space on my disk.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The folder contains a few interesting things, in particular there is `/var/lib/apt/keyrings/` directory for any repositories that you've added to the system via `apt-add-repository` ( and then there's also `/etc/apt/trusted.gpg` and `/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/`) and `cdroms.list`  which should reference the installation media as source of packages. Removed `/var/lib/apt/keyrings/ubuntu-archive-keyring.gpg` may be reinstalled with `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-keyring`.

There's also `/var/lib/apt/lists`, which contains lock files for when `apt` is running update or upgrade, and lists of packages in remote repositories. Items in that directory sometimes are cleared or deleted as in [this post](https://askubuntu.com/q/335794/295286) for example. It should regenerate once you run `apt-get update`.

In short, I wouldn't worry about this much. Just run `sudo apt-get update` and it should be back, however if you have added repositories via `apt-add-repository` which may have required a GPG key, then you may want to add that key again or temporarily remove that repository from `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`.

Although it's not a huge issue in this case, as [Lightness](https://askubuntu.com/users/157348/lightness-races-in-orbit) mentioned in the [comments](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1099511/accidentally-deleted-var-lib-apt/1099512?noredirect=1#comment1812059_1099512), the core of the issue is the accidental use of `rm -rf`. A user should realize full responsibility when they wield commands which can do damage to their system. There's countless examples on AskUbuntu and other StackExchange sites where users delete or change ownership of the core system components. From the point of view of new users it can be understandable that new users are not familiar with how much damage can be done, although that does not free the new user of the responsibility. There's no point in condemning either the command or the user, but the right way should be developing habits of verifying your own steps in command-line or elsewhere. This does not just apply to Ubuntu but computing in general, and comes with experience and often through actually making the mistakes and breaking your system only to repair it and break again. One has to be at peace with the fact that you are in control of the system and with the responsibility that comes from mistakes, and that often you'll learn a thing or two from breaking and fixing things.

Comment: You will also want to review how the error was made in the first place, because writing out `sudo` followed by `rm -rf` followed by an unintended directory name followed by `*` should not be something your brain allows to happen. Corrective action/changes to behaviours may be required to avoid much worse problems in the future.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I think this comment should be placed under OP's question, but I do agree -  user has to know what they type and avoid doing `rm -rf` without checking and ensuring that they remove the right thing first.

Comment: Well I think it should be added to the answer is why I put it here :) Comments under the question should be for suggesting clarifications to the question

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Fair enough. I've added a few notes about that.  I don't mind people contributing to my answers, so if you have something to add - feel free to edit.

Comment: To expand on Sergiy's post; As a general rule of thump, whenever you use a remove command with a wildcard (*), you should run the command with `ls` instead of `rm` first, so you can be sure that you have reviewed what you are going to delete.

Comment: @KasperThystrupKarstensen Agreed. Often  you can also see `echo` being prepended first to a command you intend to run with wildcard or other destructive commands. For example, `echo rm /tmp/*` type of thing

Comment: That's spot on, thanks. Of course it's not like I've never made such a mistake, but I immediately reviewed the error and adjusted my practices, such that I never made it again :) It's a formative experience as long as you learn from it.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Well said

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit the reason behind this accident is that I was trying to remove **/var/lib/apt/lists/*** because of its huge size to create empty space on my disk.