# I cannot run any package manager

Tags: apt, package-management, 20.04

Whenever I try to use a package manager, like Apt, GDebI, etc, I end up with an error like

E: Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock. It is held by process 25800 (aptd)

N: Be aware that removing the lock file is not a solution and may break your system.

E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/

or something telling me only one manager can be used at once.  I have tried
https://phoenixnap.com/kb/fix-could-not-get-lock-error-ubuntu and many others.
please ask if you need any more information.

Comment: It has been happening for 3 days over 2 restarts

Comment: An update to the OS did recently fail, but it has been closed

Comment: This is probably a duplicate of [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/335794/could-not-get-lock-var-lib-apt-lists-lock), which was closed as a dupe of [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15433/unable-to-lock-the-administration-directory-var-lib-dpkg-is-another-process). Though they are slightly different errors they have the same meaning.

Comment: If deleting the lock didn't fix it, this leads me to believe something is still using `apt`. I suggest you make sure you have no automatic updaters or other package-related software running and reboot again. Let's also delete some of these comments before the mods have to ;)

Comment: I just did a full shutdown and restart, nothing doing

Comment: when I open software updater, I get this [window](https://imgur.com/a/KbkHEdn)

Comment: Let's see the full error.  Add the full output of `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade` into the body of your question.  Please retain all line breaks and use the formatting tools above the edit window or Markdown to format the text in a monospace font.

Comment: Apt Upgrade crashed my PC, when it started it worked again