# APT Update not responding as expected

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, dpkg

I have tried to resolve the following issue in Ubuntu, but so far have only been able to resolve the issue by rebooting my Linux box.

I was running the `sudo apt update` command and soon realized that I had no internet for some reason. So I pressed the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> keys to stop the process. When I was sure the internet was back online, I attempted to restart the `sudo apt update` command and encountered the following error:

```
root@myubuntu-OS:/home/root# apt update
Reading package lists... Done
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
```

Other than restarting the system, is there a way to clean up my mess and run this process again?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock](https://askubuntu.com/questions/335794/could-not-get-lock-var-lib-apt-lists-lock)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> does not stop a process (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> does that). Instead, it moves it to the background. You have to execute `fg` command in the same terminal to move `sudo apt update` back to the foreground. This is why when you tried `sudo apt update` a second time it failed - the process in the background already locked `apt` (only one process should be using `apt` at once, so it locks it to prevent multiple processes from interfering with each other).

If you have closed this terminal then remove lock-files by

```
sudo rm -v /var/lib/dpkg/lock* /var/cache/apt/archives/lock
```

and then run

```
sudo apt update
```

again.

Comment: Excellent feedback! Thank you I received some feedback telling me to run                           lsof /var/lib/dpkg/lock which did the job. But your answer, gave me the information to understand what was going on and thus understand much more then copying and pasting a command string. Give a man a fish and he will eat for a day. Teach a man how to fish and he will eat forever. Thanks again for your excellent answer

Answer (score 0):

It's locked because another process is using it. This was a result of killing the task while it was operating, leaving the lock in place.

The easiest solution is to reboot, or you can remove lock files using [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1378106).

If this continues to happen even when you did not kill the update task, it's probably because your system is behind on updates and your GUI software center or unattended-upgrades has placed the lock to download the list of available software and make critical security fixes.

You can prevent this by routinely running `sudo apt update` followed by `sudo apt upgrade` to keep your system up-to-date.