# security updates not installing - missing directory

Tags: updates, security

I have just updated from 21.04 to 22.04.

A couple of times after booting I get a requestor about updates.
I click the "INSTALL" and it goes off and starts to do it's thing.
Then says "Can't install, check internet connection".

Today I remembered to try to do the update myself.

This is what happened:

```
me@me-desktop:~$ sudo apt update
[sudo] password for me: 
Reading package lists... Done
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock. It is held by process 2757 (packagekitd)
N: Be aware that removing the lock file is not a solution and may break your system.
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
me@me-desktop:~$
```

How do I resolve this problem?

Comment: If you have not rebooted, run `ps -aux | grep 2757` and see if that process really is held by Packagekit.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock](https://askubuntu.com/questions/335794/could-not-get-lock-var-lib-apt-lists-lock)

Comment: Are you sure about the Ubuntu version numbers in your question?

Comment: Thanks.   I won't worry about this problem any more.